# How to add link in PHP text?

Tags: php, function, hyperlink, logic, echo

I am looking for a way to make these paragraph fields clickable links

```
$address = rtrim($address, ", ");
echo "
<div class='col-md-3 col-sm-12'>
    <h6>".$values->Fields[0]->Value."</h6>
    <p>Address: ".$address."</p>
    <p>Phone: ".$values->Fields[6]->Value."</p>
    <p>Website: ".$values->Fields[7]->Value."</p>
    <p>E-Mail: ".$values->Fields[8]->Value."</p>
</div>";

if($cell_count == 4){
    $cell_count = 0;
    echo "</div>";
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi all you have to do is replace that code with this

```
$website_clean = str_replace("http://", "", $values->Fields[7]->Value);
                $website_clean = str_replace("https://", "", $website_clean);
                echo "<div class='col-md-3 col-sm-12'>
                    <h6>".$values->Fields[0]->Value."</h6>
                    <p class='bottom-hline'><i class='fa fa-map-marker'></i> ".$address."</p>
                    <p class='bottom-hline'><i class='fa fa-phone'></i> <a href='tel:".$values->Fields[6]->Value."'>".$values->Fields[6]->Value."</a></p>
                    <p class='bottom-hline'><i class='fa fa-globe'></i> <a href='".$values->Fields[7]->Value."' target='_blank'>".$website_clean."</a></p>
                    <p><i class='fa fa-envelope'></i> <a href='mailto:".$values->Fields[8]->Value."'>".$values->Fields[8]->Value."</a></p>
                </div>";
                if($cell_count == 4){
                    $cell_count = 0;
                    echo "</div>
```

This will do the trick

Comment: Just providing code without giving context or explaining it is not a useful answer. Additionally you added font awesome classes without knowing if OP has font awesome installed or not.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly advice you to have a quick google search "html hyperlinks".

There are different keywords in a hyperlink that tells the agent (browser) how to handle the following link.

```
[keyword]:[link]
```

So for instance you need a phone number to be linked:

`<a href="tel:+11111111111">+11 111 1111</a>`

There are more keywords for mail etc. But for that try to use google first.

Answer (score 0):

Please reference Strings section in PHP docs:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

For echoing out HTML blocks you could use double quotes:

```
echo "
<div class='col-md-3 col-sm-12'>
    <h6>{$values->Fields[0]->Value}</h6>
    <p>Address: {$address}</p>
    <p>Phone: <a href='tel:{$values->Fields[6]->Value}'>{$values->Fields[6]->Value}</a></p>
    <p>Website: <a href='{$values->Fields[7]->Value}'>{$values->Fields[7]->Value}</a></p>
    <p>E-Mail: <a href='mailto:{$values->Fields[8]->Value}'>{$values->Fields[8]->Value}</a></p>
</div>
";
```

This is far more readable. Note the `<a>` tags to generate links. For phone and mail you can prepend with `tel:` and `mailto:`.